# Select from two tables inside an insert statement in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

i am trying to insert a statement contains WHERE from two different tables :

the table i want to insert into is dbo.order

the other two tables are :

- dbo.users. user_id.
- dbo.packages. package_id.
- another order field "notes".

the statement i tried is

```
insert into dbo.order 
     (customer_id,package_id,notes) 
 Select user_id,Package_ID 
 from
      dbo.users,dbo.packages 
 where 
     username = 'bader' AND  package_name = 'beginner','notes value here';
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you making a copy of an order or do you want to update an order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no obvious join here so you'll get the cartesian product of Bader orders and beginner packages. Not sure what the notes value should be. If its a literal you can just include it in the select clause.

```
insert into dbo.order 
     (customer_id,package_id,notes) 
 Select 
       user_id,Package_ID , 'notes value here'
 from
      dbo.users,dbo.packages 
 where 
     username = 'bader' AND  package_name = 'beginner';
```

Comment: its still give me this erorr : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. i am trying in sql server query :  insert into webage.dbo.order (customer_id,package_id) Select user_id2, Package_ID from dbo.users, dbo.packages where username = 'bader' AND  Package_name = 'lite'

Comment: ok it worked , it seems that the word "order" already reserved in sql server , so when i change the table name into "orders" it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into dbo.order 
     (customer_id,package_id,notes) 
 Select user_id, Package_ID, 'notes value here'
 from
      dbo.users, dbo.packages
 where 
     username = 'bader' AND  package_name = 'beginner';
```